# In R , a question about change variable type to 'factor'

Tags: r, forcats

I use the code below to change the variable 'period' from 'character' to 'factor' (and factor levels sequence to match the order contained in 'period' text).

Below is the current code. Is there an available function for it ?

```
library(tidyverse)

raw_data <- 
  data.frame(
    period=c('Q2','Q1','8','7','40','41'),
    amount=c(1:6)
  ) 


arranged_data <- raw_data %>% arrange(match(parse_number(period),c(1:41))) %>% 
  mutate(period=fct_inorder(period))
```

Comment: Your example returns an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lvls <- unique(raw_data$period)
raw_data$period <- factor(raw_data$period, levels = lvls[order(parse_number(lvls))])
```

Resulting in:

```
levels(raw_data$period )
[1] "Q1" "Q2" "7"  "8"  "40" "41"
```

Answer (score 1):

```r
> raw_data %>% mutate(period = factor(period)) %>% as_tibble()
# A tibble: 6 × 2
  period amount
  <fct>   <int>
1 Q2          1
2 Q1          2
3 8           3
4 7           4
5 40          5
6 41          6
```

As you can see, you just have to call the `factor()` function on a vector to convert it into a factor.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,  but I want to the factor levels as   【 "Q1" "Q2" "7"  "8"  "40" "41"】  （it is the resule of   'levels(arranged_data$period)' ）

Comment: Do you know beforehand what order you want? In this case you can do `factor(period, levels=c("Q1", "Q2", "7", "8", "40", "41")`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work! The issue is that `fct_inorder` doesn't change column type, so you should turn the column into a factor first:

```
library(tidyverse)

raw_data <- 
   data.frame(
      period=c('Q2','Q1','8','7','40','41'),
      amount=c(1:6)) 
    
arranged_data <- raw_data %>% arrange(match(parse_number(period), c(1:41))) %>%
   mutate(period = as.factor(period)) %>%
   mutate(period=fct_inorder(period))
```